# Laravel Excel me genera un xls vacío

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Tengo problemas a la hora de generar un xls con Laravel Excel, hago un filtrado de datos, los cuales los manejo con el siguiente controlador

```
$consulta = Directorio::join("judicatura", "judicatura.id_judicatura", "=", "usuarios.id_judicatura")
    //->where("vetting", $vetting)
    ->whereIn('departamento', $request->departamentos)
    ->whereIn('cargo', $cargos)
    ->whereIn('tipo', $request->judicaturas)  
    ->orderBy("departamento", "asc")
    ->orderBy("usuarios.id_judicatura", "asc")
    ->orderBy("cargo", "asc")
    ->orderBy("tipo", "asc")
    ;

    $_SESSION['con'] = ["consulta" => $consulta->toSql(), "parameters" => $consulta->getBindings()];
    $usuarios = $consulta->select("*")->paginate(5000);
            
    return view($request->view, compact('usuarios'));
```

Se me pide que al mostrar la vista con los resultados, no se genere el archivo de excel, si no hasta que se presione el botón de descargar, en el controlador anterior paso en una variable de sesión la consulta en crudo, con sus respectivos parámetros, consulta que utilizo en la siguiente función (que está dentro de un controlador de reportes)

```
public function exportarExcel(){        
    $directorio = new DirectorioController;
    $obj = (Object) $_SESSION['con'];
    $array = new DirectorioExport($obj);
    return Excel::download($array, 'directorio.xlsx');
}
```

Envío el objeto que contiene la consulta al Export.

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnWidths;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;
class DirectorioExport implements ShouldAutoSize, WithHeadings, WithStyles, WithColumnWidths, FromQuery
{
    protected $rawQuery;
    protected $parameters;

use Exportable;

 public function __construct($query)
 {
     $this->rawQuery = $query->consulta;
     $this->parameters = $query->parameters;
 }

 public function query(){
    return collect(DB::select($this->rawQuery, $this->parameters));
 }

public function headings(): array
{
    return [
        'NOMBRES',
        'APELLIDOS',
        'CARGO',
        'CORREO',
        'DUI',
        'TELEFONO'
    ];
}

public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
{
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:F' . $_SESSION['cuenta']+1 , $sheet->getHighestRow())->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $sheet->getStyle('A:F')->getAlignment()->setVertical(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:F1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $sheet->getStyle('A:F')->getFont()->setSize(8);
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:F1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $sheet->getPageSetup()
    ->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    $sheet->getPageSetup()
    ->setPaperSize(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_LETTER);
    $sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);
    $sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(0);
    $sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('&C&HDirectorio Telefonico' . '&C' . "\n" . ' Direcotiro SMJ');
    $sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('&L&B' . $sheet->getTitle() . '&C&D&T&RPagina &P of &N');
    
}

public function drawings(Worksheet $sheet){
    $drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
    $drawing->setName('Logo');
    $drawing->setDescription('Logo');
    $drawing->setPath(public_path('/img/cnj.png'));
    $drawing->setHeight(36);
    $drawing->setWidth(36);
    $drawing->setCoordinates("A1");
    return $drawing;
}

public function columnWidths(): array
{
    return [
        'A' => 20,
        'B' => 20,
        'C' => 45,
        'D' => 30,
        'E' => 10,
        'F' => 10
    ];
}
```

}

En la función query() genero la consulta para obtener los datos, el archivo se descarga sin darme ningún error, sin embargo el xls me viene solo con el encabezado, no tengo ningún registro de los generados por la consulta.

Mencionar que realicé una prueba dentro del controlador de reporte (un return con la query generada) y ahí me genera la información correcta.

De la forma que lo hice antes, y que me funciona, es generar toda la consulta y guardarla en variable de sesión y ya en el export utilizar la función collection(), pero no me satisface esa opción.

¿Tienen alguna idea de como poder solucionar eso? de antemano, gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando un exporter implementa la interfaz `FromQuery`, se espera que el método `query` [devuelva una instancia del query builder](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html). Análogamente, cuando implementa `FromCollection` se espera que el método `collection` devuelva [una colección](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html). (Principio de [Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment#:%7E:text=The%20principle%20of%20least%20astonishment,not%20astonish%20or%20surprise%20users.)).

En tu pregunta indicas que usando `FromQuery` se genera una planilla vacía, mientras que usando `FromCollection` sí te funciona. Esto ocurre porque el job encargado de poblar la planilla con registros, intentará obtenerlos mediante algo equivalente a:

```
  $export->query()->get()
```

Pero tu método `query` desde ya retorna una colección

```
public function query(){
  return collect(DB::select($this->rawQuery, $this->parameters));
}
```

Y cuando se invoque sobre ésta el método `get`, sin argumentos, arrojará un `TypeError`. ¿Por qué no estás viendo este error? Diría que es porque ocurre dentro de un job y pasará desapercibido si no estás mirando los logs.

Como ya habrás adivinado, si tu empeño es usar `FromQuery` entonces necesitas adaptar el método `build` para devolver una instancia de Builder.

¿Cómo adaptarlo? Eso es cosa tuya, pero siguiendo el paradigma DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) sería sensato usar la query que hoy tienes en tu controlador, cosa que cualquier modificación a la consulta se haga en un solo lugar asegurando la consistencia entre ambas salidas.

```
class DirectorioExport implements FromQuery etc etc  {

    // constructor y otros métodos
    // etc etc 

    public function query() {
         return  Directorio::join(
            "judicatura", "judicatura.id_judicatura", "=", "usuarios.id_judicatura"
         )
        ->whereIn('departamento', $this->departamentos)
        ->whereIn('cargo', $this->cargos)
        ->whereIn('tipo', $this->judicaturas)  
        ->orderBy("departamento", "asc")
        ->orderBy("usuarios.id_judicatura", "asc")
        ->orderBy("cargo", "asc")
        ->orderBy("tipo", "asc");
    }

    // otros métodos...
       
}
```

Conviniendo en que el exporter será instanciado, para poblar ya sea la vista o la planilla, con los departamentos, cargos y judicatura que corresponda. No creo que el link necesario para generar la descarga sea muy distinto del que hoy usas para generar la vista.

```
public function show(Request $request){        
    $directorio = new DirectorioExport(
         $request->only['departamentos','cargos','judicaturas']
    );

    $usuarios = $directorio->query()->select("*")->paginate(5000);
            
    return view($request->view, compact('usuarios'));    
}

public function exportarExcel(Request $request){        
     $directorio = new DirectorioExport(
          $request->only['departamentos','cargos','judicaturas']
     );
    return Excel::download($directorio, 'directorio.xlsx');
}
```

Como comentario al margen... ¿Será buena idea que la vista a renderizar se defina en el request? ¿No será arriesgado confiar tanto en un input de terceros?